# Sharepoint Workflow 2013 does not automatically start unless started using user has contribute permission on site level

Tags: workflow, permissions

I have created a SharePoint 2013 `On Adding` workflow using VS2012.

If I login with an user that has **site-level contribute** permission, then the workflow is triggered normally as expected but if I login with a user who has `contribute` permission only on at **list level**, the workflow does not start and following error is thrown:

> "HTTP 401 {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action"

How can I trigger the workflow for users who don't have site level `contribute` permissions?

Comment: Can you briefly explain around what you are tyring to achieve using the workflow. You probably need to grant the user access to more entities than just the list that you are talking about.

Comment: I write to history using WriteToHistory, create Workflow Task using SingleTask, get current user using LookupSPUser, get current workflow task using GetTaskListId and LookupSPListItem. Note:I already Grant the login user by contribute permission on WorkflowTaskList and WorkflowHistoryList

Answer (score 1):

Your users need the following permissions -

1. `Contribute` to `Workflow History` - 
    to get to the list , go to *site url/WorkflowHistory/AllItems.aspx*
2. `Read` to `Workflow Tasks`
3. `Read` to the Site
4. `Read` to the List

To manage permissions, navigate to its list settings, go to "permissions for this list" and give the requisite permission to the target user. It is advised that you create a group with the above set of permissions, and add users to this group as required.

Comment: thank you Swayam Siddha for your reply, I tried your advice but I faced the same issue "the workflow does not trigger for users who don't have site level contribute permissions"

Comment: Don't the users need Contribute access to the Workflow Tasks list as well?

Comment: Afaik, only approvers need contribute action

Comment: finally I found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx) that solve all what I need